# React Router - 404 page renders first on protected route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have `/control-panel` page protected but when I go to `/control-panel` page 404 page renders first then loads the page, any idea how to fix?

code:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
    <Route exact path='/help' component={FAQ} />

    {admin ? <PrivateRoute authed={userSignedIn} path="/control-panel" exact component={ControlPanel} /> : null}

    <Route component={NoMatch} />
  </Switch>
```

Updated to:

```
{!my_protected_urls.includes(window.location.pathname) && <Route component={NoMatch} />}
```

Comment: It depends on how you are getting the values of `admin`. 
For eg, if it is after setState, you can use callback function to return the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening as the value of `admin` is not true before this code is executed.

As I indicated in my comment, it depends on how you are getting value of `admin`

An easier workaround for the situation, however, will be using `pathname`.

Try this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
    <Route exact path='/help' component={FAQ} />

    {admin ? <PrivateRoute authed={userSignedIn} path="/control-panel" exact component={ControlPanel} /> : null}

    {window.location.pathname!=='/control-panel' && <Route component={NoMatch} />}
  </Switch>
```

This should fix your issue. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 'admin' value is set before the router initialized and 
try this.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
  <Route exact path='/help' component={FAQ} />

  {admin ? <PrivateRoute authed={userSignedIn} path="/control-panel" exact component={ControlPanel} /> : null}

  <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: yea, needed to set up admin value before switch `admin && <Switch></Switch>` worked out

Comment: actually if I do that /help page got blocked by admin its no longer public.

Comment: what do you mean by got blocked?

Comment: so like if I signed in as admin I can see control-panel and help, but if I sign out I cant see /help

Comment: can you update your code snippet to latest what u have in <Router> ?

Comment: you are setting admin condition on all routs, please check my snippet

Comment: also one other thing to consider is to move that admin check inside private route or create new rules out type AdminRoute